# Export Windows Event Logs with Powershell

Tags: c++, powershell

Is there a way to export ALL Windows Event Logs possibly through the Event Log Manifest with PowerShell or any other coding method? The objective is to not only export event logs in Security, Application or System, but all possible Event Logs available in Microsoft. This would have to be something to include a description, name, and ID?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of tweaks you could do here, but this is the basic gist.  "-ListLog *" will get you all the log names and then you just step through them.  "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" is due to logs with no events generating errors.  You could trap the specific exception (NoMatchingEventsFound) if you want to see other errors.

```
$Logs = Get-Winevent -ListLog *

foreach ($Log in $Logs) {
  Get-WinEvent -LogName $Log.LogName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for the reply. One thing I am seeing is Errors saying 'Could not retrieve information about the Microsoft-Windows Firewall with Advanced Security/ConnectionSecurityVerbose log, etc. Is this due to that log not being enabled?

Comment: Also, to clarify. I don't want to export events that occurred on the system. I want to generate a list of all types of Windows events with accurate descriptions. You would think Microsoft would have a list SOMEWHERE available online.

Comment: OK, just to make sure I understand, you want a list of possible event sources and event ids with a description?  There is no definitive source for Windows as multiple pieces are managed by different teams.  If you search for event ids you will get taken to different TechNet or MS Doc pages.  Depending on applications you have installed it could vary. There is a registry key with all the registered sources and DLLs that you might be able to enumerate and query, but I don't know how helpful that would really be.

Comment: Do you have a possible way to query those Reg keys? And that's the problem, there is no TRUE source.

Comment: I can help you with enumerating all of the DLLs, but do you think you can follow these docs to pull out the data?  I don't have time to dig into that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/message-files

Comment: I posted another answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to list all the registered message DLLs this is how you do it:

```
$lognames = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\ | Select Name
$DLLs = foreach ($logname in $lognames) {
    $providers = gci $logname.Name.Replace('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:')
    foreach ($provider in $providers) {
        $item = get-itemproperty  -Path $provider.name.replace('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:')
        $item.EventMessageFile
    }
}
```

After that you could step through the $DLLs and use the docs reference below to extract data.  I haven't looked at how to do this, but if it's .Net you can likely do it in PowerShell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/message-files

Comment: Thank you, I will have to test this

Comment: Scott, so I was able to successfully pull all of the DLLs with what you suggested, however I am not too proficient with C++.

I've seen some things on how to query the registry keys with PowerShell, but nothing sound. Do you have any ideas?